# php if else program, using first "if" statement and ignoring the rest

Tags: php, if-statement

Im trying to get a php program that will ask for a name and age and give an output

I got the name and age but the else if section is not working it only goes to the "if" the rest get ignored even if i change the age appropriately.

their is no visible error given by the program, it runs just not as intended

```
echo 'your name is: '.$_GET["name"].'<br>';
echo "<br>";
echo 'your age is: '.$_GET["age"].'<br>';

if(isset($_Get["age"]) <=20)
{
echo "you are under the drinking age<br>";
}



elseif(isset($_Get["age"]) >=21 OR isset($_Get["age"]) <=35)
{
echo "you are a young man";
}

elseif(isset($_Get["age"]) >=36 OR isset($_Get["age"]) <=60)
{
echo "you are a middle aged man";
} 

elseif(isset($_Get["age"]) >=61 OR isset($_Get["age"]) <=100)
{
echo "you are asenior citizen";
} 

elseif(isset($_Get["age"]) >=100 )
{
echo "WOW your really old!!";
}
```

output:
your name is: adam

your age is: 42
you are under the drinking age

Comment: I think you want `AND` operators instead of `OR`

Comment: I think you will find it will work if you replace all instances of "OR" with "AND". Whilst you are at it, why not make a single call to isset($_Get["age"]) and store the result in a local variable, using that for all your comparisons.

Comment: This is failing for way too many reasons.

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean value.  Effectively this means it is either `0` or `1` so only your first `<=` check will pass.  And it will always pass!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to modify your conditions as per your requirements.

As per your code and explanations, I think you want like this:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="number" name="age">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) { // condition is run only when the form is submited
    $name = $_GET["name"]; // store name in variable
    $age = $_GET["age"]; // store age in variable

    echo 'your name is: '.$name.'<br>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'your age is: '.$age.'<br>';

    if($age <=20) { // 20 or less then 20
        echo "you are under the drinking age<br>";
    } else if($age >=21 && $age <=35) { // 21 to 35
        echo "you are a young man";
    } else if($age >=36 && $age <=60) { // 36 to 60
        echo "you are a middle aged man";
    } else if($age >=61 && $age <=99) { // 61 to 99
        echo "you are asenior citizen";
    } else if($age >=100 ) { // Up to 100
        echo "WOW your really old!!";
    }
}
?>
```

Please check this code and try to understand what I did and let me know if you any question.

Comment: Thank you it does work the "submit" part really got me for a sec but i figureed it out

Answer (score -1):

use [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to check if a number is in your desired range or not

```
<?php

echo ValidateAge(25);

function ValidateAge($Age){
if ($Age == filter_var($Age , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 21, 'max_range' => 35)))) $Answer = 'you are a young man';
if ($Age == filter_var($Age , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 36, 'max_range' => 60)))) $Answer = 'you are a middle aged man';
if ($Age == filter_var($Age , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 61, 'max_range' => 99)))) $Answer = 'you are asenior citizen';
if ($Age >= 100) $Answer = 'WOW your really old!!';
return $Answer;
}
```